# Timer issue in C# with threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am developing a skype-like application, I have an external DLL that do most of the work and fires events handled in my class ip2ip, one of this events is incoming_call fired when there is an incoming call as the name suggest. I'm trying to manage missed calls.
Now this is the relevant part of the code in this class:

```
    private void ics_IncomingCall(object sender, string authenticationData, int socketHandle, string callbackid, string callbackipaddress, int callbackvideoport, int callbackaudiotcpport, int callbackaudiudpport)
    {
        if (Calling)
        {
            ics.RejectCall("The contact have another call", (IntPtr)socketHandle);
            Message = "An incoming call from [" + callbackipaddress + "] has rejected.";
        }
        else
        {
            AcceptIncomingCall = null;

            UserCaller = FindUserName(callbackipaddress);

            IncomingCall = true;

            //waiting for the call to be accepted from outside of this class
            while (AcceptIncomingCall.HasValue == false) Thread.Sleep(100);

            if(AcceptIncomingCall.Value == true)
            {
                //call back to have a 1 on one video conference

                icc.Parent.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    //accept the incoming call

                    ics.AcceptCall("n/a", socketHandle);

                    icc.Call(callbackipaddress, callbackvideoport, 0, 0,
                        "n/a", callbackid,
                        ics.GetLocalIp()[0].ToString(), 0, 0, 0, "");

                    Calling = true;
                }));
            }
            else
            {
                ics.RejectCall("Call not accepted", (IntPtr)socketHandle);
                Log = "Incoming call not accepted";

                Calling = false;
            }

            AcceptIncomingCall = null;

            IncomingCall = false;
        }

    }
```

IncomingCall is a property generating a PropertyChangedEvent, wich is captured in my main class where I have this code:

```
    private void ip2ip_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.PropertyName) == false)
        {

        ..............
            if (e.PropertyName.Equals("IncomingCall") && ip2ip.IncomingCall == true)
            {
                Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate 
                    { 
                        pnlCalling.Visible = true;
                        aTimer.Start();
                    }));
            }
         ................

        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        .......
        aTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        aTimer.Interval = 10000;
        aTimer.Tick += aTimer_Tick;
    }

    void aTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer.Stop();
        btnNo.PerformClick();
    }
    private void btnNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer.Stop();
        ip2ip.AcceptIncomingCall = false;
    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer.Stop();
        ip2ip.AcceptIncomingCall = true;
    }
```

I need the timer to manage the missed call, when there is an incoming call a panel appears, with buttons to accept/reject the call. If the user waits too much the call is considered rejected (missed).
In this way it doesn't work, probably I'm doing something wrong with the timer, as without any timer everything works. I also tried the timer of the class System.Timers with same results. Any Idea?

**EDIT**

This is my expectation, there is an incoming call so the event `ics_IncomingCall` is fired, `IncomingCall=true` cause the execution to go to the main class (we are still in same thread, I see it debugging step by step in VS) where is invoked in the GUI thread the panel to be visible and started the timer, now we have one thread where a while loop block the execution until in the other thread user do something (accept/reject).
The problem exist when the user accept the call, the code after the while loop is always executed, the caller has no problem at all and receive the stream, but in the receiver (who receive the stream as I verified in wireshark) the DLL (who is responsible to show the incoming video) fails to do its job for some reason unknown to me but caused by the timer.

Comment: I understand that you expect the timer to work in parallel with `while (AcceptIncomingCall.HasValue == false)`. That is: you want the given method to wait for that condition to be true, but also the timer to keep track of the time and, eventually, be triggered before this loop is exited. If I understand the situation/your expectations well, your code wouldn't be right: the while loop is avoiding the code to go beyond it (including the timer), you should manage this situation in a different way (e.g., taking care of this issue with multithreading rather than with a loop blocking everything).

Comment: You might prefer to analyse a much simpler situation of the problem to understand what is happening/should be done properly. For example: create an application with a timer started in the load form event and, right after it, an infinite loop. You would see that the tick event is never reached and would be able to easily test different alternatives.

Comment: You are right about my expectations, but I don't understand. I think my problem happens inside the DLL, because when the user accept/reject/miss the call the code after the while loop is executed (I tried this going step by step debugging), I also know this because the caller has no problem, but in the receiver no incoming video is showed (the data is exchanged, checked with wireshark). The problem should happens in DLL but is caused by the timer, as I have no problem removing it. I guess I did something bad with the timer causing some kind of thread-related problem, causing problem in my DLL.

Comment: No. Your code is not meant to work as you expect (I insist: do the simple test I am recommending above and confirm it yourself). The while loop blocks the GUI thread where the timer is also running (well... the timer is a bit special; but this loop blocks it anyway). In certain situations (e.g., an error being triggered at some point), the behaviour might be somehow different, but this doesn't mean that is right. You need to create two different threads: one for waiting and another one for the timer; what means that only need to create an additional one (the timer can use the GUI thread).

Comment: In any case your code is not too clear. If you want to get help, you should simplify the problem and post something easily understandable. What I am proposing above is not just for you to understand the exact behaviour loop + timer, but also to help you transmit what you are doing/expecting properly. You don't need to post here your whole code; some times, it is better to post a simplistic code clearly describing the problem.

Comment: I updated my question to better clarify, it's not simple to explain my problem as I'm using a proprietary DLL, so I can only guess which problems Timer is causing. I also tried what you wrote, but seems to me to be a different situation.. in my case the while loop reside in a different thread from the timer (that is in the GUI thread), I see this debugging. In my case however the code after the while loop is always executed...

Comment: The problem (if I understood it right) is not that the code after the while loop is executed, but that the timer (its tick event) cannot be reached until that happens. That is: after the timer is started, the loop keeps the GUI thread waiting until the next income call; during this time, the timer will not work at all. If this is the problem, you could fix it by making a new thread for the loop which does not block the GUI thread.

Comment: I hope that something of what I wrote has been of help, but I have already spent too much time here. Next time, you should make an extra-effort to transmit the problem clearly; just posting a not-clear code is not good for your interests (either no answers or time being wasted with comments and clarifications).

Comment: The timer works.. it rises the event when the interval elapses (after the start), and it doesn't if the user accept/reject the call. I'll post the whole code somewhere, I think it's the best solution, however I'm starting to think that the problem is not related to the timer, but it's a DLL issue..

Comment: As said in my previous comment, I have spent already more than enough time here (better wait for the next person willing to help). In any case, you should take care of all the debugging by your own, locate the problematic parts, try to understand what is going on there and, in case of having any specific doubt, you might ask here (by posting only relevant parts). Posting a whole big code is a quite bad idea: eventually, someone might take a quick look and say something (like I did), but don't expect more than that. The better you use this site, the quicker you will get (accurate) answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate your question does not include [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Having such a code example would make it much more practical for someone to provide a useful answer.

That said, as explained by commenter [varocarbas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065481/timer-issue-in-c-sharp-with-threads#comment55890497_34065481), your fundamental problem appears to be that you have blocked the UI thread (with the `while` loop), while at the same time hoping for the UI thread to handle other activity (such as the timer's tick event). In fact, you are also preventing the button click from having an effect. The button `Click` event handlers can't execute either, while the UI thread is blocked.

*One* possible way to fix this would be to use a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` to provide the `ics_IncomingCall()` with a waitable object, which the buttons and timer can use to signal. For example:

```
// Change from "bool?" to this:
private TaskCompletionSource<bool> AcceptIncomingCall;

public void HandleCall(bool accept)
{
    AcceptIncomingCall.SetResult(accept);
}

private async Task ics_IncomingCall(object sender, string authenticationData, int socketHandle, string callbackid, string callbackipaddress, int callbackvideoport, int callbackaudiotcpport, int callbackaudiudpport)
{
    if (Calling)
    {
        ics.RejectCall("The contact have another call", (IntPtr)socketHandle);
        Message = "An incoming call from [" + callbackipaddress + "] has rejected.";
    }
    else
    {
        AcceptIncomingCall = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        UserCaller = FindUserName(callbackipaddress);

        IncomingCall = true;

        //waiting for the call to be accepted from outside of this class
        if (await AcceptIncomingCall.Task)
        {
            //call back to have a 1 on one video conference

            icc.Parent.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                //accept the incoming call

                ics.AcceptCall("n/a", socketHandle);

                icc.Call(callbackipaddress, callbackvideoport, 0, 0,
                    "n/a", callbackid,
                    ics.GetLocalIp()[0].ToString(), 0, 0, 0, "");

                Calling = true;
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            ics.RejectCall("Call not accepted", (IntPtr)socketHandle);
            Log = "Incoming call not accepted";

            Calling = false;
        }

        AcceptIncomingCall.Dispose();

        IncomingCall = false;
    }

}
```

and:

```
void aTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    aTimer.Stop();
    btnNo.PerformClick();
}

private void btnNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    aTimer.Stop();
    genericServerClient.HandleCall(false);
}

private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    aTimer.Stop();
    genericServerClient.HandleCall(false);
}
```

This causes the `ics_IncomingCall()` method to return when it reaches the `await` statement, allowing its thread to continue executing. The button `Click` event handlers will call back to the public method that encapsulates your field (public fields are very dangerous and should be avoided in almost all situations), setting the result value for the `TaskCompletionSource` object that is being awaited.

Once the result value has been set, this will cause the framework to resume executing your `ics_IncomingCall()` method where it left off, but now with the value returned from the button `Click` event handlers. I.e. `true` if the user clicked the `btnOk` and `false` if they clicked `btnNo` or the timer interval elapsed.

Note that this changes the signature of your `ics_IncomingCall()` method, which will force a change to the caller. The best way to handle that will be to change the caller as well, to be `async` and to use `await ics_IncomingCall(...)`. That will of course force a change in *its* caller, and its caller's caller, and so on. But you need to release the UI thread, and this is the best way to do it. Hopefully you don't have a lot of callers to change, but even if you do, this is the way to go.

If the above does not seem to address your problem, please provide a good MCVE. Note that a good MCVE is both *complete* and *minimal*. You will want to remove from the example any code that is not strictly required to reproduce the problem. At the same time, make sure someone can copy and paste the code into an empty project and have it run with at most *very minimal* effort, and preferably none at all.

Comment: Thank you Peter, I can not however see clearly what you describe. You say the GUI thread is blocked, but running my application all the instruction in GUI thread are executed (did debug step by step with F11), the panel is shown, timer started...if you wait too much the tick is executed, or if you click accept your video is send to the other peer (this means instruction after while is executed with the value coming from the button clicked), but for some reason you won't see the incoming video (the DLL is in charge to do this) for some problem I believe related to the timer.

Comment: I will try anyway to reproduce my issue with a MCVE.. I'll post it!